# What do "Tea-Paw" and "Tea-Paw Tax double header" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the word, ‘*Tea-Paw’* in headlines of articles of both Time magazine (March 31) and StarTribune (March 1st).

Time's headline says "The *Tea-Paw* tax double header," followed by the lead copy, "Minnesotan heads to Boston on Friday ahead of Des Moines on Saturday."

StarTribune’s headline says "*Tea-Paw*: Birth of a candidate?" followed by the lead copy, "Minne‘Former Minnesota Governor, Tim Pawlenty released a new video Tuesday highlighting his speech at a weekend tea party convention in Phoenix.

What is Tea-Paw? Is it a combination of ‘Tea party’ and “(Tim) Pawlenty”? If it is (or not), what is “Tea-Paw tax double header”?
Does the word 'Tea-Paw" pass itself as the common currency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

T(im) Paw(lenty) is frequently called [T-Paw](http://www.timpawlenty.com/bio) for short. Mix that with *Tea Party* and you get *Tea-Paw*.

A double header because Time magazine reported (from Reuters)

> Minnesotan in Concord, Boston Friday ahead of Des Moines Saturday

which seems to have been updated from

> Minnesotan will appear at Des Moines 10:30 AM CST April 15 Tea Party rally ahead of Boston 4-6 PM EST event

as in two baseball games on the same day.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Per your explanation, I thought Tea-Paw is combination of Tea (Partty) and (Tim) Paulenty, and I know doubleheader as a baseball- related jargon. Still question remains - What is ‘Tee-Paw tax?’

Comment: Tax just means his speeches were about taxation, a topic of particular interest to the Tea Party. The original Boston Tea Party was a protest organised by smugglers objecting to cheap legal tea undercutting their business.